# redirecting all urls with .cfm files using regex in .htaccess files from .cfm to .php with Query Strings

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all urls which ext is .cfm to .php in same file with same requested query sting.

Example : -

From

> example.com/index.cfm?queryString=1234

to

> example.com/index.php?queryString=1234

urls may or may not have queryStrings.

All website pages with .cfm should redirect to .php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.cfm$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

If you want full redirect then add `R` flag above as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.cfm$ /$1.php [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: what is the meaning of full redirect, I don't know, I want to use Query String also.

Comment: Query string is automatically forwarded to new URL. Did you test it? Full redirect makes URL change in browser.